# how to rectify this error "InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify-sdk-js

i'm trying to create a AWS cognito login with fb. the proble is it is throwing error from this API (
https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ --> 400 error) like:

```
{
    "__type": "InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException",
    "message": "Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool."
}
```

how to rectify it as resources are low in the internet for this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the provided information it seems that you have not assigned proper `IAM role` with required permissions for cognito see the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html) and double check that you have set proper `identity provider` fb in your keys with necessary info and provided the right `client_id`